# how to store the field value in the scanner

Tags: java, string, field, java.util.scanner, assign

I am trying to assign the value `String` in my `Scanner`, Shall I use `nextLine()` as it might contain more than a word or shall use `next()`?
The original codes are too long and I can't paste them all anyway. The method has a parameter `Scanner scanner`, and this method is called by another class and it passes an instance of other class, all what I want to know is how to access the fields using the `Scanner`

```
private String name;

private String id;

 public void readData()
    {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner();

       name = scanner.nextLine();

       id = scanner.nextLine();
       }
```

Comment: What exactly do you scan here? Your code wouldn't compile in the first place, because there is no constructor `public Scanner()` in the `Scanner` class. Instead, you might want to use `Scanner(File source)` , `Scanner(InputStream source) ` or `Scanner(String source) `.
Please take a look at the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: sorry m8 its my fault, the original codes are propa long and i cant past them all anway the method has parameter Scanner scanner, and this method is called by another class and it passed an instance of other class, all what i want to know is how to access the fields using the scanner

Comment: Well, the question stands.. **what does your scanner scan?** Is it a `string`? Is it a file? That is it?

Comment: it scans the fields of type String

Comment: Okay, the fields of type `String` are stored somewhere. They can be substrings of a string, they can be stored in a file. For example you might have a text file and want to get the strings from it. Or you might have a `String` variable and you want to get substrings, for example the words of a phrase

Answer (score 0):

Use the `nextLine` method to read all of what is on the current line. It is possible for the current line to only have a newline character which would return an empty string.

I think the Id either using `scanner.next()` or `scanner.nextLine()` is the same because id is one value but `next()` is better in my opinion, but for the name you would probably use `nextLine()` method .